# File Type returning as UNKNOWN on certain servers

Tags: c#, server, remote-desktop

I have an application that is used on different environments. I have an area in which I display a set of documents and I print the file type in brackets so that the user knows what they are downloading. This works perfectly fine on my test site but on my live site, the file type is returned as UNKNOWN. The code is exactly the same on both environments so I don't believe it is anything in the code that is causing the problem.

My question is, I was wondering if there were any changes that I need to make to my live server settings within IIS in order to read the file type correctly on live as is on my test site?

Comment: Could you please let us know the file type?

Comment: @GulamHusainAnsari PDF

Comment: If this file type use at server side then adobe reader should be install on server as well, If it use only at client side then only client machine should have adobe reader. better is to do proper logging in code and know the exact reason, other wise I am agree with you that there is no code issue.